# how to position the QIcon in the Qt table item?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qicon

I want a table cell with text aligned to the left and icon aligned to the right side.

But now, im getting both icon and text left aligned, here what i have tried

```
QtTableWidgetItem * item = new QtTableWidgetItem("program");
item -> setIcon(icon);
ui -> tableWidget -> setItem(i,j,item);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manage the position of the icon and the text you must use a delegate, in this case I use the `QStyledItemDelegate` and I overwrite the `initStyleOption()` method:

#### C++ version

**aligndelegate.h**

```
#ifndef ALIGNDELEGATE_H
#define ALIGNDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class AlignDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
protected:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        option->decorationPosition = QStyleOptionViewItem::Right;
    }
};

#endif // ALIGNDELEGATE_H
```

Then it is established in the delegate:

```
AlignDelegate *delegate = new AlignDelegate(ui->tableWidget);
ui->tableWidget->setItemDelegate(delegate);

QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem("foo text");
item->setIcon(icon);
ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, j, item);
```

[image]

#### Python version:

```py
class AlignDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.decorationPosition = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.Right
```

```py
delegate = AlignDelegate(view)
view.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```